# Is mongodb running?

Tags: mongodb, unix, database, nosql

I have installed Mongodb and the PHP drivers on my Unix server.

My question is how can I tell if Mongodb is running? Is there a simple command line query to check status? If I start it once from the shell will it keep running if I exit the shell (this doesn't seem to be the case). How can I make the Mongodb connection persistent and auto start on server reboot?

I can run:

```
-bash-3.2$ su  
Password:  
[root@xxx]# cd /var/lib  
[root@xxx]# ./mongodb-linux-i686-1.6.5/bin/mongod  
./mongodb-linux-i686-1.6.5/bin/mongod --help for help and startup options  
Wed Feb 23 08:06:54 MongoDB starting : pid=7271 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 32-bit  

** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data  
**       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations  

** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ. This is known to be broken!!!  

Wed Feb 23 08:06:54 db version v1.6.5, pdfile version 4.5  
Wed Feb 23 08:06:54 git version: 0eb017e9b2828155a67c5612183337b89e12e291  
Wed Feb 23 08:06:54 sys info: Linux domU-12-31-39-01-70-B4 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri  
Feb 15 12:39:36 EST 2008 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_37  
Wed Feb 23 08:06:54 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017  
Wed Feb 23 08:06:54 [websvr] web admin interface listening on port 28017
```

If I open a separate shell I can then then connect to mongodb:

```
-bash-3.2$ cd /var/lib  
-bash-3.2$ ./mongodb-linux-i686-1.6.5/bin/mongo  
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.5  
connecting to: test  
> db.foo.find()  
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d63d7d3eb95985ab19c8feb"), "a" : 1 }
```

However if I close the initial shell I can't connect:

```
-bash-3.2$ cd /var/lib  
-bash-3.2$ ./mongodb-linux-i686-1.6.5/bin/mongo  
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.5  
connecting to: test  
Wed Feb 23 08:25:10 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 (anon):1154  
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 176):

check with either:

```
ps -edaf | grep mongo | grep -v grep  # "ps" flags may differ on your OS
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/mongodb status     # for MongoDB version < 2.6

/etc/init.d/mongod status      # for MongoDB version >= 2.6
```

or

```
service mongodb status         # for MongoDB version < 2.6

service mongod status          # for MongoDB version >= 2.6
```

to see if mongod is running (you need to be root to do this, or prefix everything with `sudo`). Please note that the 'grep' command will always also show up as a separate process.

Check the log file `/var/log/mongo/mongo.log` to see if there are any problems reported.

Comment: You can also do a `pgrep mongo`.

Comment: I got this: 501  5365   418   0  4:10pm ttys000    0:00.00 grep mongo, does that mean it is running?

Comment: service mongod status not worked for me, but service mongodb status is worked.

Comment: from mongo 2.6 the service is mongod earlier its mongodb, confusing yes

Answer (score 52):

I find:

```
ps -ax | grep mongo
```

To be a lot more consistent. The value returned can be used to detect how many instances of mongod there are running

Comment: Also, you may want to consider adding a filter to not return the grep process you are running. So: ps -ax | grep -v grep | grep mongo

Answer (score 46):

For quickly checking if mongodb is running, this quick nc trick will let you know.

```
nc -zvv localhost 27017
```

The above command assumes that you are running it on the default port on localhost.

For auto-starting it, you might want to look at [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61503/how-to-start-mongodb-server-on-system-start).

Comment: Yes, this works if just checking if something is listening to the port. If that is the case, the output will contain `27017 open`, or else `Connection refused`.

Answer (score 19):

On Ubuntu ([doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/))

> sudo systemctl status mongod

**If running**

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-10-14 14:13:40 UTC; 3s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 1604 (mongod)
     Memory: 210.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
             └─1604 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

**If not running**

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
```

**To start mongodb**

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Answer (score 18):

this should work fine...

```
pgrep mongod
```

Answer (score 13):

To check current running status of mongodb use: `sudo service mongodb status`

Comment: I don't think you need `sudo` for `status`

Answer (score 8):

Correct, closing the shell will stop MongoDB. Try using the `--fork` command line arg for the mongod process which makes it run as a daemon instead. I'm no Unix guru, but I'm sure there must be a way to then get it to auto start when the machine boots up.

e.g.

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend
```

Check out the full documentation on [Starting and Stopping Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo).

Comment: Thanks. I got this: `[root@xxx lib]# ./mongodb-linux-i686-1.6.5/bin/mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/m
ongodb.log --logappend
all output going to: /var/log/mongodb.log
forked process: 7518` but still when I close the shell and open a new one I get `Connect failed`

Comment: hmm, works for me (Ubuntu 64bit VM, Mongo v1.7.6), so I'm not sure why it's not for you tbh. If you can't get it working, best bet may be to post it on the mongodb forums: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user

Comment: But I started it with `&`, and now I can't find the processid.

Comment: @bobobobo - how are you trying to find the process ID?

Comment: `ps -e | grep mongod`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below command, to check MongoDB status, e.g: `sudo service MongoDB  status` which displays the status of MongoDB service as like the screenshot:

[image: MongoDB status]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`sudo systemctl status mongod`

Answer (score 2):

Probably because I didn't shut down my dev server properly or a similar reason.
To fix it, remove the lock and start the server with:
`sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock ; sudo start mongodb`

Answer (score 2):

To check whether the server is running *on a `systemd` operating system*, in a manner more suitable for use in a shell script, use

```
systemctl is-active mongod
```

rather than

```
systemctl status mongod
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is for php, but I got here looking for a solution for node. Using mongoskin:

```
mongodb.admin().ping(function(err) {
    if(err === null)
        // true - you got a conntion, congratulations
    else if(err.message.indexOf('failed to connect') !== -1)
        // false - database isn't around
    else
        // actual error, do something about it
})
```

With other drivers, you can attempt to make a connection and if it fails, you know the mongo server's down. Mongoskin needs to actually make some call (like ping) because it connects lazily. For php, you can use the try-to-connect method. Make a script!

PHP:

```
$dbIsRunning = true
try {
  $m = new MongoClient('localhost:27017');
} catch($e) {
  $dbIsRunning = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### For macOS

If you installed the MongoDB using brew command then these commands will be useful

1. `$ brew services start mongodb-community` **This command will start the server**
2. `$ brew services stop mongodb-community` **To stop the server use this command**
3. `$ brew services restart mongodb-community` **And for restart, you can use this command**

Comment: `$ brew services list` https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

i am running from a container, so this command worked for me (showing the mongo sys info):

```
/usr/bin/mongod --sysinfo
```

or from a docker commandline:

```
docker exec mongodb /usr/bin/mongod --sysinfo
```

** where mongodb is the name of the container (you can replace it with container id)

the result should look something like this:

```
{
    "sysinfo": {
        "_SC_PAGE_SIZE": 4096,
        "_SC_PHYS_PAGES": 8208877,
        "_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES": 7318176
    }
}
```

Comment: This command works regardles of whether server is running or not. Try `mongod --shutdown`, then `mongod --sysinfo` - the `--sysinfo` one will still succeed. So, it is useless for the purpose.