# Finding MongoDB details after hosting on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, deployd

I'm completely new to setting up servers, MongoDB, and still a little new to Javascript.

I'm trying to upload a [Deployd server onto an online server](http://docs.deployd.com/docs/server?include=all). There is limited information on this, so at the moment, I set up a simple *AWS Ubuntu* server by doing the following tutorials:

http://zenborgium.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-setup-deployd-on-ubuntu-server.html

http://terraltech.com/how-to-setup-deployd-on-ubuntu-server/

However, I'm stuck at creating the `production.js`. There's a guide on it [here](http://docs.deployd.com/docs/server/run-script.md). I'm specifically stuck at this line of code:

```
var server = deployd({
  port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
  env: 'production',
  db: {
    host: 'my.production.mongo.host',
    port: 27105,
    name: 'my-db',
    credentials: {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    }
  }
});

server.listen();
```

Where do I find the `host`, `port`, `name`, and `credentials` that I should use from MongoDB? The tutorials say I need to use my own data, but I don't know where or how to find them.

Comment: On a side note, I have no idea if AWS is suitable for this at all. I heard this might be more suited with Heroku, but couldn't find a guide on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to have MongoDB installed. I haven't used Deployd myself, but I will give you some information regarding the config file.

- If you are running Mongo on the same ubuntu server as your application, you can use `localhost` to connect.
- Default Mongo install runs on port `27017`, in other words `localhost:27017`.
- The 'name' parameter is just a name you give your database. So here you can put whatever you want, ex `my-db`.
- With a clean Mongo install, you don't need any credentials. You have to set that up yourself if you want. I suppose leaving them out of the config file is ok, if not needed.

Your config file should therefor look something like this:

```
var server = deployd({
  port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
  env: 'production',
  db: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    name: 'my-db'
  }
});
```

*update*
I had a quick look at the tutorial you linked to. In one of the tutorials they created a user for mongodb. If you followed this step, you need to put that login information into you connect-object under credentials.

*update 2*
To get information about your mongodb install, check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091624/is-mongodb-running)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Didn't work though. At least I know that it wasn't my problem. Is there any way of knowing what server and port mongo is running on?

Comment: First; I gave you wrong port number for mongodb default install. Updated the post now. Right port number is 27017. Try with the new port number instead. See also my update regarding getting information about mongodb.

Comment: Still didn't work. Debugging isn't turning up much, it looks like the settings for everything is right, but it just doesn't connect from the outside. I even tried `mongo localhost:27017/my-db
` which turned out fine. I'll check it out after the weekend.

Comment: Did you solve your problem Muz? I'm running into the same issue, can't connect from the outside