# Mongodb problem_could not connect to server

Tags: mongodb

I use ubuntu 14.04LTS and with mongodb version 2.4.9.When I type "mongo" in terminal, it always show "connecting to: test
Tue Jun  3 10:03:57.911 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed".
But if i run mongod in one terminal, and run mongo in another, all is ok.
If I close the window of mongod, the connection fail again.
I need to use mongodb without open a terminal of mongod, how can I do with it ?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is mongodb running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091624/is-mongodb-running)

Answer (score 0):

You need to start mongodb as a service or daemon(depending on the OS,in your case daemon), check the documentation

[Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#StartingandStoppingMongo-RunningasaDaemon)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Or

To run a `mongod` process as a daemon (i.e. fork), and write its output to a log file, use the `--fork` and `--logpath` options. You must create the log directory; however, mongod will create the log file if it does not exist.

The following command starts mongod as a daemon and records log output to /var/log/mongodb.log.

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log
```