# How to check for running process or service in gradle

Tags: mongodb, gradle, continuous-integration

I have a gradle build, which runs a few tests on our application. Currently the tests that store assets in mongoDB fail if the developer forgets to run mongod first. So I want any build that uses mongoDB to fail with a message the user that clearly tells him to start mongoDB. Ideally, later we would start mongoDB from gradle.

I already found this nice article about [how to see if mongoDB is running under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091624/is-mongodb-running), which is quite simple. I am sure something similar can be done under Windows using `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq mongod"`, etc. But I need to know how to use this correctly in gradle.

Is there a cross platform way to check if a service or normal process is running in gradle?

Comment: Better (assuming using Groovy or Java) embedded solution for testing such as  [flapdoodle](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo). Using [mongo plugin](https://github.com/sourcemuse/GradleMongoPlugin)

Comment: Yes we are using testng, so that is Java

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion provided by Orid to use the [Gradle Mongo Plugin](https://github.com/sourcemuse/GradleMongoPlugin) should work if you set the necessary Gradle tasks to be dependent on a `startManagedMongoDb` task.

While that may seem to be the easiest way, it may be breaking with how MongoDb will be used in non-development environments or on a continuous integration build-server, where the MongoDb service will already be running.

A very simple solution would be to add the MongoDb checking functionality to the top of a customized `gradlew.bat` (and the `gradlew` bash script if it will be run on a *nix operating system).

Another simple solution that wouldn’t require changing the `gradlew.bat` script would be to create your own MongoDb checking script that then called `gradlew.bat`, passing on command line arguments. I’m not sure if there is an equivalent to the bash `$@` for all positional arguments in windows, but looping through the arguments with `SHIFT %1` can be used to generate the `gradlew.bat` command line.