# Cannot connect to a mongodb service in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud, I have a database service, which is running in front of a mongodb deployment. I also have a series of microservices, which are attempting to connect to that datastore.

However, they can't seem to find the host.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
   name: mongo
 name: mongo
spec:
 ports:
 - port: 27017
   targetPort: 27017
 selector:
   name: mongo
```

Here's my mongo deployment...

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo:latest
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - name: mongo
          containerPort: 27017
          hostPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mongo-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: mongo-disk
            fsType: ext4
```

And an example of one of my services...

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bandzest-artists
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: bandzest-artists
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: artists-container
        image: gcr.io/<omitted>/artists:41040e8
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 7000
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: DB_HOST
          value: mongo
        - name: AWS_BUCKET_NAME
          value: <omitted>
        - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          value: <omitted>
        - name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
          value: <omitted>
```

Comment: Where are you attempting to connect from?

Comment: @BrettJ in one of my services, I have a go API. So my services live in an API pod, my mongo server is in another Pod, behind another service. So there are API pods and a datastore Pod.

Comment: So you're saying that connecting to mongo.default:27017 doesn't work from inside a pod?

Comment: Trying to understand the connection to App Engine. Is that where the Go service is running?

Comment: @iamnat I was just connecting to `mongo:27017` I'll try using `mongo.default:27017` instead

@BrettJ The go service is within a pod, the pod is behind a service, then I have a mongodb server on a separate pod, behind a separate service named 'mongo'

Comment: @BrettJ That didn't seem to work either

Comment: If you can use alpha features, there is an example within helm: https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/pull/74 using petsets and init-containers in kubernetes.

Comment: It appears you tagged this with "app engine" and its not related to that. Accurately using tags is important.

Comment: @BrettJ You're correct, apologies

Comment: @EwanValentine don't forget to create the gcePersistentDisk before you use it and make sure it's not mounted to something else.  I've updated my answer to include that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, check that the service is created

`kubectl describe svc mongo`

You should see it show that it is both created and routing to your pod's IP.  If you're wondering what your pod's IP is you can check it out via

`kubectl get po | grep mongo`

Which should return something like: `mongo-deployment-<guid>-<guid>`, then do

`kubectl describe po mongo-deployment-<guid>-<guid>`

You should make sure the pod is started correctly and says `Running` not something like `ImagePullBackoff`.  It looks like you're mounting a volume from a `gcePersistentDisk`.  If you're seeing your pod just hanging out in the `ContainerCreating` state it's very likely you're not mounting the disk correctly.  Make sure you [create the disk](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#creating-a-pd) before you try and [mount it as a volume](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#example-pod-2).

If it looks like your service is routing correctly, then you can check the logs of your pod to make sure it started mongo correctly:

`kubectl logs mongo-deployment-<guid>-<guid>`

If it looks like the pod and logs are correct, you can exec into the pod and make sure mongo is actually starting and working:
`kubectl exec -it mongo-deployment-<guid>-<guid> sh`

Which should get you into the container (Pod) and then you can try [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5521155/316857) to see if your DB is running.

Comment: Figured it out! Mongodb was complaining about a lack of CPU resource, I upped it, re-provisioned the stack, and it connected straight away! Your debugging tips were a huge help, thank you so much!