# Connect to a DB hosted within a Kubernetes engine cluster from a PySpark Dataproc job

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, google-kubernetes-engine

I am a new Dataproc user and I am trying to run a PySpark job that is supposed to use the MongoDB connector to retrieve data from a MongoDB replicaset hosted within a Googke Kubernetes Engine cluster.

Is it there a way to achieve this as my replicaset is not supposed to be accessible from the outside without using a port-forward or something?

Comment: Maybe I can do this from an init part in my script that will run a port-forward and then kill it at the end of the job?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I assume by saying "outside" you're pointing to the internet or other networks than your GKE cluster's. If you deploy your Dataproc cluster on the same network as your GKE cluster, and expose the MongoDB service to the internal network, you should be able to connect to the databases from your Dataproc job without needing to expose it to outside of the network.

You can find more information in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/network#create_a_dataproc_name_short_cluster_with_internal_ip_addresses_only) to know how to create a Cloud Dataproc cluster with internal IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think your link is broken!

Comment: Ok thanks! So from what I understand, I simply have to check the "internal IP only" option and to create my cluster under the same network my GKE cluster is and I should be able to reach my nodes by using their IP. Am I right?

Comment: About the fact to check the `Internal IP only` option, does it mean I wont be able to reach the internet from my nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Just expose your Mogodb service in GKE and your should be able to reach it from within the same VPC network.

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058003/cannot-connect-to-a-mongodb-service-in-a-kubernetes-cluster) for reference.

You should also be able to automate the service exposure through an init script

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my mongodb replicaset is already exposed via a service (and not an ingress) which is why it is not reachable from outside of my kubernetes cluster without using something like a port-forward. Is it what you recommend me to do in an init script? Because I am not sure this is really good practice, is it?

Comment: It seems I can instead use an internal load balancing https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing